# SSH socks proxy through multiple "Jumps"

Tags: ssh, socks5

I would like to create a SOCKS proxy for accessing a few remote HTTP apps through multiple SSH jumps.

My intent would be as follow:

```
myHost:4321 -> HostA(sshd) -> HostB(sshd) -> HostsX(app)
```

If there wasn't the need to pass through **HostB**, the command for creating the SOCKS proxy would be as simple as:

```sh
ssh -D 4321 HostA -N
```

But I don’t know how to add a "jump" to the command; for example the following errputs the usage message:

```sh
ssh -D 4321 -o ProxyCommand='ssh -J HostA' HostB -N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-J` is an alternative to (some class of) `-o ProxyCommand=`, (usually) not an addendum. You use it as straightforwardly as:

```
ssh -ND 4321 -J HostA HostB
```

This is [how `-J` works](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#J):

> `-J destination`
> Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host described by `destination` and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there. Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters. […]

Note `ssh -J HostA HostB` is *not* equivalent to connecting from local to HostA and then from HostA to HostB. It's equivalent to connecting from local to HostA and then from local to HostB (using packets forwarded through HostA).

If you specified more jump hosts (e.g. `-J HostA,HostX,HostY,…`) then a connection to each extra host would be established via a tunnel connecting your local machine and the previous host. The connection to the ultimate destination would use a tunnel ending at the last jump host. All connections would start at your local system.

So it's not like a daisy chain. It's like nested tubes (tunnels), where each tube of smaller and smaller diameter uses the previous (slightly larger) tube and connects your local system to a point further and further away.

Wrong picture, daisy chain:

```
local ###> HostA ===> HostX +++> HostY ---> destination
```

Right picture, nested tubes:

```
      ###> HostA
      ==============> HostX
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++> HostY
      ------------------------------------>
local                                       destination
      ------------------------------------>
      +++++++++++++++++++++++++>
      ==============>
      ###>
```

This means if you want to use private keys with `ssh -J` then only keys available to your local `ssh` will matter. No SSH client will be invoked on any jump host; your private keys (if any) stored on jump host(s) will be irrelevant.