# Start port forwarding between two remote machines from a third computer

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

Suppose I have a computer compute_mine. I have ssh access to two remote computers compute_remote_1 and compute_remote_2. I would like to forward a port from compute_remote_1 to compute_remote_2. However, I would like to initiate and control the port forwarding process from compute_mine. No data from compute_remote_1 or compute_remote_2 should be forwarded to compute_mine.

I need the port forwarding to be automatically terminated when the process on compute_mine terminates for whatever reason. I would also like to avoid multiple ssh instances.

A rough approximation would be an ssh ProxyCommand issued from compute_mine as follows: On compute_mine: ssh into compute_remote_2 'ProxyCommand forward port from compute_remote_1 to local port on compute_remote_2'

I have tried various ssh ProxyCommands but nothing has worked so far. Any suggestions ?

I have tried various ssh ProxyCommands issued from compute_mine to remote_compute_2. For example: ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -W host:port user@remote_compute_1 -v' user@remote_compute_2 -P port_number -NTC

This quit with the error: banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: invalid format

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you try `-J` instead, like `ssh -J remote_1 user@remote_2` from compute_mine? The banner exchange error you got looks like ssh choked on the banner from the server side - take a look through the troubleshooting steps here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/656631/247007 to see if you can suppress it or get a more detailed error

Comment: The machines I am using run an older version of ssh which does not support ProxyJump. In any case, wont the jump command run a tunnel from remote_2 to compute_mine via remote_1 ? I would need a tunnel between only remote_1 and remote_2. Computer compute_mine should not listen, only issue the command for the tunnel between remote_1 and remote_2 to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to run on 'compute_mine':

ssh -L localhost:8081:localhost:8080 -o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p user@compute_remote_2" user@compute_remote_1 -N

This command sets up the SSH tunnel using ProxyCommand instead of -J.
The -W option in ProxyCommand specifies the host and port to forward to (%h:%p will be replaced by the target host and port).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it might solve your problem:

```
ssh compute_remote_1 ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 compute_remote_2 sleep 10
```

Assuming you are going to run something on your machine that uses the tunnel. You have 10 seconds to start using the tunnel after the above command has been executed (change the sleep 10 for a different value).

Once the SSH tunnel is in use the SSH commands won't terminate, however as soon as the last connection stops using the tunnel the SSH commands will terminate - which will tear down the tunnel.

You could also `nohup` the remote ssh command if you want your local SSH command to return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ProxyCommand` can help you. It acts as an alternative for the raw TCP connection. To get the idea, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/671348/108618) where `ProxyCommand` is not used for proxying. No matter what command you specify as `ProxyCommand` while invoking `ssh -L` or `ssh -R` on *compute_mine*, one end of the tunnel will be *compute_mine*. And the command specified as `ProxyCommand` is run locally, so if you in turn use `ssh -L` or `ssh -R` inside `ProxyCommand` then one end of the tunnel will be *compute_mine* as well.

Similarly with `ssh -J` [all connections begin on the local computer](https://superuser.com/a/1773922/432690), i.e. on *compute_mine* in your case. If `ssh -J` is run on *compute_mine*, a port forwarding with `-L` or `-R` will involve *compute_mine*.

To forward a port from *compute_remote_1* to *compute_remote_2* not via *compute_mine*, you need an SSH connection that starts at *compute_remote_1* or *compute_remote_2*.

From *compute_mine* you can do this:

```
# not an answer yet
ssh compute_remote_1 'ssh -NL 5678:localhost:1234 compute_remote_2'
```

The tunnel will be established by `ssh -NL … compute_remote_2` started on *compute_remote_1*. The problem is this `ssh` won't exit automatically when `ssh` running on *compute_mine* is terminated.

A solution is to use `ssh -tt` on *compute_mine*:

```
ssh -tt compute_remote_1 'exec ssh -NL 5678:localhost:1234 compute_remote_2'
```

<sup>(`-t` is usually enough, but `-tt` will do what we want even if there is no local terminal.)</sup>

This will allocate a tty on *compute_remote_1* and start a shell as the controlling process of the tty. The shell will execute `exec ssh …` an thus replace itself with `ssh`. The point is we want `ssh` to be the controlling process. Some shells `exec` the last command automatically (an optimization, a sane behavior when there is nothing more to do), but it's better to `exec` explicitly in case the shell on *compute_remote_1* is not that smart.

The easiest way to terminate the port forwarding by acting on *compute_mine* is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it the terminal where our `ssh -tt` runs (if such terminal exists). This won't directly kill `ssh -tt`, `^C` will get to *compute_remote_1* and the tty there will kill `ssh -NL` (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723585/108618)). Our local `ssh -tt` will exit later.

`ssh` on *compute_mine* may exit first for whatever reason, e.g. you may `kill` it. If this happens and if `sshd` on *compute_remote_1* notices (depending on circumstances it may or may not notice immediately, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585887/108618)), then the tty on *compute_remote_1* will be closed and the controlling process will get SIGHUP. We made sure the controlling process is `ssh` that handles the port forwarding, SIGHUP will terminate it. This way the port forwarding is automatically terminated when the `ssh` process on *compute_mine* terminates.

It's up to you if you `ssh -tt` from *compute_mine* to *compute_remote_1* or to *compute_remote_2*; and if you use `ssh -NL` or `ssh -NR` there. The "target" of port forwarding does not have to be `localhost`, so e.g. `ssh -NL 5678:compute_remote_2:1234 compute_remote_3` on *compute_remote_1* may make sense. Adjust the solution to your needs.